# light-symbol.el to only light matching symbol's background and not refontify it

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use light-symbol.el to show matching symbols on the page to where the cursor is at. It has been working very well except that it completely strips the matching symbols from their original color scheme and then highlights the background. I tried to miss around with the code to have it only highlight the background without resetting the coloring of the symbols but did not succeed.
Any help is appreciated.
Here is the related code take from light-symbol.el:

```
(defun light-symbol-refontify ()
  (unless font-lock-mode
    (font-lock-mode 1))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
(defun light-symbol-show-symbol ()
  (when (and light-symbol-mode
             ;; FIXME: this should prevent us from changing when
             ;; isearch is running but does not... ?
             (not this-command))
    (let ((refontify nil))
      (when light-symbol-previous-symbol
        (font-lock-remove-keywords nil light-symbol-previous-symbol)
        (setq refontify t))
      (let ((sym (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
        (if sym
            (progn
              (set-text-properties 0 (length sym) nil sym)
              (setq light-symbol-previous-symbol
                    (list (list
                           (concat light-symbol-rx-start
                                   (regexp-quote sym)
                                   light-symbol-rx-end)
                           (list 0 (list 'quote light-symbol-face) t))))
              (font-lock-add-keywords nil light-symbol-previous-symbol)
              (setq refontify t))
          (setq light-symbol-previous-symbol nil)))
      (if refontify
          (light-symbol-refontify)))))
(defun light-symbol-pre-command ()
  (when light-symbol-previous-symbol
    (font-lock-remove-keywords nil light-symbol-previous-symbol)
    (setq light-symbol-previous-symbol nil)
    (light-symbol-refontify)))
```

This is the link to the library:
https://raw.github.com/nealford/emacs/master/elpa/light-symbol-0.1/light-symbol.el

Comment: `M-x customize-face RET light-symbol RET` ? (speculation). Also, please *link* to third-party libraries.

Comment: Phil, I added the link to the library.
I might have not explained my issue clearly since your response doesn't address the problem. The way this library works is that it first "removes any customized fonts from the symbol it matches" then it "highlights the background color". I want the code above to be modified so it wont do the first step, I still want the customized font to be visible but just add the background color on matching symbols.

Comment: Right, I didn't see the `(set-text-properties 0 (length sym) nil sym)` in there. That seems a bit heavy-handed, but I rarely mess with syntax highlighting, so maybe there's some justification for doing it. My assumption was that it simply applied the face in `light-symbol-face` (which actually turns out to be `'hi-blue` by default) to the text, and that customising the face to only modify the background should be enough, but clearly that's not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out this line:

```
(set-text-properties 0 (length sym) nil sym)
```

That may do what you're asking for. I don't know if it's a robust solution, because I don't know why that was done in the first place.

Obviously if the text colour is similar to the light-symbol face background, you'll not be able to read it.

If you want to control the foreground colour as well to prevent the low contrast issue, you could `defface` a custom face (or just find an appropriate existing face that sets both foreground and background; always assuming you don't want to mess with the `hi-blue` face), and set `light-symbol-face` to that instead.

That might not be dramatically different to what you started with, however.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried Phil. Did not work.
I found highlight-symbol-el library. Did everything I was looking for. So I am dropping light-symbol.el all together.

Comment: Righto. FWIW I tried it out in Emacs 24.3 (started with emacs -Q) before posting that, and commenting that line out seemed to do the trick for me.